# equality in $p$-adic analysis

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I'm reading a paper of recurrences sequences and I could not understand why the equality mentioned in the underlined lines in the image. I think that it has to do with $p$-adic analysis. If someone has a clue or an answer, I would appreciate it very much. I have added some more information

[image]
[image]